# ios: shouldAutorotate of presented view controller is not called

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, uiviewanimationtransition

Consider I have three ViewControllers: **A**,**B** and **C**.

A will support only LandScapeRight Orientation,

B will support all kind of Orientation,

C will support only LandScapeRight Orientation.

I will present ViewController B  on A and ViewController C on B. I have overriden respective methods, shouldAutorotate and preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation methods and returned required orientations. Everything works fine.

The problem comes when I use custom modal presentation for Viewcontroller C.
Viewcontroller C will rotate in all the direction which ViewController B supports. i.e, overriden methods of ViewController B are also called.

Can anyone please help to solve this issue?

Comment: Could you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)